# Retornar pixel de uma determinada cor analisada pelo ImageGrab

Tags: python, python-3.x, pillow

Preciso identificar uma cor em um "retângulo" de pixels e retornar a posição dela para salvar em uma variável. Por exemplo, nesta imagem, preciso detectar a cor azul, e quando detectada ele me retorna a posição X, Y dela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei criar o seguinte código em Python para realizar essa tarefa, porém ele não funciona. Pesquisei em muitos fóruns sobre, porém não obtive resultados. O que posso estar fazendo de errado ?

```py
from tkinter import *

from PIL import ImageGrab
import pyautogui

running = False


def capture_screen():
    global screen
    screen = ImageGrab.grab()
    return screen


def scanning():
    if running:
        screen = capture_screen
        for x in range(1658, 1766):
            for y in range(31, 138):
                check_pixel = screen.getpixel((x, y))
                print("Check pixel", check_pixel)
                resolution = pyautogui.size()
                print(resolution)
    root.after(80, scanning)


def start():
    global running
    if running != True:
        running = True
    elif running == True:
        running = False


def stop():
    global running
    running = False


root = Tk()
root.title("Tstes")
root.geometry("100x100")

app = Frame(root)
app.grid()

start = Button(app, text="Start Scan", command=start)
stop = Button(app, text="Stop", command=stop)

start.grid()
stop.grid()

root.after(1, scanning)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Murilo tenta seguir nessa linha:

```
from tkinter import *

from PIL import ImageGrab
import pyautogui

screen = ImageGrab.grab(bbox =(x1, y1, x2, y2)) 
screen.show()
```

Onde x e y, são posição e tamanho do print que voce quer capturar

feito isso faça o for para iterar sob x e y igual você montou no exemplo (Só precisa alterar o range, para ficar igual ao que voce quer)

Dentro do laço do For basta usar:

```
check_pixel = screen.getpixel((x, y))
print("Check pixel", check_pixel)
```

Aqui voce tem de colocar  de alterar o (255,255,255) para o rgb do azul que voce quer capturar, e caso encontre só jogar em uma variável o x e y atual

```
 if check_pixel ==   (255,255,255):
       print('a')
```